# Name this (2-D, logic-table-like, visual) programming language/paradigm (Subtext/Example Centric Programming)

Tags: programming-languages, paradigms, subtext, visual-programming

I remember stumbling upon a video clip introducing a new programming "language" and a paradigm. The "language" was 2D and visual in nature, and therefore tightly coupled with its IDE and interpreter in the video.

It started out like a truth table but got more complicated. Conditionals were represented in the X axis and the flow in the Y axis of the program.

For example, to build an "absolute value" function, one defined inputs and outputs, let's call them integer `I` and integer `O`. Clicking on `I` allowed one to define a subcase, say `I < (const)`. One then entered `0` as the constant and the `I` column split into two: `I < 0` and `I >= 0`. One connected both to `O`, one of them through a `neg` function and got the absolute value function.

The point was that missing cases were immediately and visually identifiable; defining two cases `x < 0` and `x > 0` immediately split the `x` column into three and if you forgot to connect the `x = 0` case to the output, it would be obvious.

This is about as brief as I can be while still supplying enough information for people to identify and/or get interested about the language, so I'll cut it here. It may look like it only solves some specific problems to do with conditionals and logic, but I remember the "language" being strong enough to be a paradigm on its own.

The video also made some good points about how modern programming wasn't that much different from what it was some 50+ years ago, i.e. typing text, which is fundamentally 1-D, on a teletype.

Question: What's the name of the language/paradigm/IDE/interpreter?

I'm mainly looking [for the name] to find and watch the video again, so I can discuss it with my current colleagues. If you have more to say about it, we can turn this question into a community wiki and start discussing.

Comment: A 2D language? Reminds me of Befunge and friends...

Comment: 2D but not text. Think more of a "graph" language where you connect the input through filters to an output. But this is inside something like a logic table and more generic than most visual languages listed on the Wikipedia page. Hmm, I think I'll try going through them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are talking about [Subtext](http://subtextual.org/subtext2.html)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Uhhhh, is it Logo?  That is all that springs to mind.

Comment: Nope, the source code wasn't text. It was more like a graph, though not really a graph; connections and expressions in a table.